# Can you deploy a fake backend run by json-server NPM module using Heroku?

Tags: heroku, json-server

I often use the npm module `json-server` to generate a fake JSON api given a `db.json` file. Is there any way to deploy that to Heroku? Essentially, I just run

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

And it runs a server that also servers static html if there are any in the `public/` directory. Essentially, I think it is just running a Node server, except I tried pushing to Heroku, but it did not work. Is there a special procedure I should do in order to make Heroku run that `json-server` module as my server?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm trying to to the same for XHR mock backend

Comment: @Adam, I actually did solve it. Here is the repository: https://github.com/nbkhope/fake-restful-api

One thing I was not able to do was redirect the logging produced from json-server to the app. It would be great if anyone helped with that. Make a pull request and contribute! Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the login logic in the repo. I think the json-server can return a successful login status and the redirect would need to be done with something like jQuery unless you're using Angular or some other framework. If you update your repo I can take a look.

Comment: @AdamMendoza I am not sure what you are saying. When I said logging, I meant console logs whenever a request is made to the server. Something displaying in the terminal saying GET /whatever was requested, etc.

Comment: I misread that as login vs. logging. I'll post update.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to consume your fake APIs from an application published on Heroku, AWS Elastic Beanstalk etc., use My Json Server https://my-json-server.typicode.com/ . As far as I know, it is free for a small json.db file.

All you need to do is:

1. Create a repository on gitHub and put your json.db there
2. Call you API `https://my-json-server.typicode.com/<your-github-username>/<your-github-repo>`

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, Heroku will look for a startup-script, this is by default `npm start` so make sure you have that in your `package.json`.

Late to the party, but in case someone needs, just check out [this repo](https://github.com/jesperorb/json-server-heroku), change the `db.json` to what you want, then follow step-by-step instructions to deploy to Heroku.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following command to start json server

```
  `json-server --watch db.json -p 3001 -d 2000
```

Here -p is port
This is commond to start local json server on port 2000

Comment: Here -p is port

Comment: This is commond to start  local json server on port 2000.